# Using find function

Tags: matlab

Consider the following arrays:

```
A = [1 3 4 5 6 7 1 3 7];
B = [1 4 7];
```

I want to find all elements of `B` in array `A`. So, my final output array will look something like:

```
C = [1 7 3 6 9];
```

First element of `B` is at locations 1 and 7 in array `A`, so `C` has 1 and 7 as first two elements. Element 4 of B is at location 3, so array `C` has 3 as its third element and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of C is required?

Fast, but another order:

```
find(ismember(A,B))
```

Slower, but the order you want:

```
cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x)(find(A==x)),B,'UniformOutput',false))
```

Basically, the second solution iterates over all elements of B and applies `find(A==x)` in a loop.

You may also delete the cell2mat, then a cell is returned. First element -> Occurrences of 1, second element-> occurrences of 4 etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you need the result in that order: you can use the two outputs of `ismember`. This may be faster than [Daniel's answer (second part)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21709753/2586922) as it avoids `arrayfun`:

```
[tf, loc] = ismember(A,B);
loc = loc(tf);
ind = find(tf);
[~, order] = sort(loc);
C = ind(order);
```

Comment: More memory efficient than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Second output of `ismember` will give a map for each element of `B`

```
>> [~,ic] = ismember(A,B)
ic =
     1     0     2     0     0     3     1     0     3
```

Then element-wise test against each element of `B`:

```
>> [C,~] = find(bsxfun(@eq,ic.',1:numel(B)))
C =
     1
     7
     3
     6
     9
```

---

And because I'm require to do so, an alternative method following `ismember`:

```
c = accumarray(nonzeros(ic),find(ic),[],@(x) {sort(x)});
C = vertcat(c{:})
```

Comment: +1 for `bsxfun`. But it may consume much memory for large `A` and `B`.

Comment: True, `bsxfun` can be quite memory heavy.